# Legendre Polynomial Sum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question has two parts:

Does the sum of the Legendre Polynomials from $L=0 \to \infty$ evaluated at $x=0$ converge? 
What about the sum of the squared Legendre Polynomials at the same point?

Comment: Great! Came up in an attempt to sum a potential. Its convergence would help me decide how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, polynomials of odd degree do not contribute to either sum. 
Bonnet's recursion formula (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)) tells us that
$$P_{2k}(0)=-\frac{2k-1}{2k}P_{2k-2}(0) \tag1$$
Hence, 
$$ P_{2k}(0) = (-1)^k \prod_{j=1}^k \left(1-\frac{1}{2j}\right)  \tag2 $$
The product on the right behaves like $1/k$ (take logarithm and recall how the harmonic series diverges). 
Therefore, $\sum P_{2k}(0)$ converges conditionally, by the alternating series test. 
And   $\sum P_{2k}(0)^2$ converges absolutely.